# AWS Dedicated instance equivalent in Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

The footnotes for Standard_D15_v2, Standard_G5, Standard_L32s Azure instance types in the [official documentation says this "Instance is isolated to hardware dedicated to a single customer"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes).

Can these be considered to be the [equivalent of AWS Dedicated instance](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6181662-add-dedicated-instances)?

Comment: Not a topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..as per this link

<kbd>[Announcing: New Dv2-series virtual machine size](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-new-dv2-series-virtual-machine-size/)</kbd>

> A larger virtual machine size has joined the Dv2-series. This new size is the Standard_D15_v2 with the following specifications: 20 CPU cores, 140 GB of memory, 1,000 GB of temporary solid-state drive (SSD), up to 8 virtual network interface cards (NICs), up to 40 data disks, and very high network bandwidth.
>
> **Each Standard_D15_v2 instance is isolated to hardware dedicated to a single customer, to provide a high degree of isolation from other customers**. This addition and the Standard_G5 are the two available sizes that are on hardware dedicated to a single customer. The Standard_D15_v2 is available in all locations that support the Dv2-series, as described on the Azure services by region page. This size is available for virtual machines that use the Azure Resource Manager deployment model and custom OS images published by Canonical, CoreOS, OpenLogic, Oracle, Puppet Labs, Red Hat, SUSE, and Microsoft.